# Do these three questions mean the same thing? And do you need a preposition when asking about places?

Tags: questions

```
To where did you go yesterday?

Where did you go to yesterday?

Where did you go yesterday?
```

I see people omit the 'to' a lot. However, I also asked a related question yesterday

```
Who did you give the keys to?

To whom did you give the keys?
```

Here, the 'to' seems necessary. Why can you omit the 'to' when talking about places?

Comment: Note that if you want to use the objective form of "who", then it's "whom" no matter what order you put the words in. So "*Whom did you give the keys to?*" would be a correct way to use "whom".

Comment: @ToddWilcox But see StoneyB's answer below. Maybe "correct" is too confining here?

Comment: StoneyB has given a great answer, i'd accept if I were you!

Answer (score 4):

*Where* has a double sense, both as an interrogative and as a relative. It may stand for either

- **a preposition phrase (PP)** denoting a location or destination—approximately equivalent to *at* or *in* or *to what/which place*

  > Where are you? = *At what/which place are you?*
  >   Where are you going? = *To what/which place are you going?*

  But its pro-PP character is already less than obvious when it's used as a relative with a nominal antecedent.

  > The place where I am going ... = *The place to which I am going ...*

  Moreover, there are instances where it is needed to designate an origin rather than a location or destination, and to avoid ambiguity *where* has to be coupled with a distinct preposition such as *from*.

  > I see where you're going, but I can't make out where you're coming **from**.

  The first of these permits and the second requires that *where* should stand for
- **a nominal designating a place**, which can act as the object of a preposition. The most formal style deprecates this pronominal use when a location or goal is designated. But this use is very common outside that style:

  > Come on, come on, lemme show you where it's at. —*Dave Clark Five*
  >   Doesn't have a point of view, Knows not where he's going to —*Beatles*

  And there's no evident reason in grammar for prohibiting *where* as object of some prepositions and not others. I myself follow the formal use (I actively avoid situations in which *where* must be employed with a preposition), and P.E.Dant speaks for his namesakes when he says that *where ... to* and *where ... at* are redundant; but those are stylistic judgments, not  grammatical ones.

  *ADDED, with thanks to ruakh for raising the matter:*
  Note, however, that even in the most colloquial registers we avoid using locative prepositions like *at* and *in* immediately before *where*—**Let me show you at where it is*— only when they are 'stranded' on the right side of the verb. Goal prepositions (*to*, *by*, *until*) and trajectory and origin prepositions (*via*, *through*, *from*) are borderline: they are apt to sound contrived in formal registers and pedantic in colloquial registers. My advice is that you avoid using *where* in situations where these constructions would be needed and instead use a frank noun: *Which road did you take?* or *What countries are you going to?*

Comment: Does **when** follow the same rules as **where**, since both time and place require a preposition? Instead of _to what place_, it would be _at what time_.

Comment: *When* can be used with a preposition, in much the same circumstances--*I remember that from when I was In Austria*--but it's much less common, perhaps because so much of the burden of defining the sense of a temporal reference rests on the verb. For instance, you'll rarely hear anybody say *From when do you work in the morning?*--instead we say *When do you start work in the morning?*

Comment: *From* might not be the best example, since it differs from other prepositions in that it can take some adverbial complements that others cannot (for example, contrast "from inside the house", which is perfectly grammatical, with \*"to inside the house" and \*"at inside the house", which are not grammatical). But there's no problem with (for example) *until when*.

Comment: Also, even in forms of the language where "where [...] to" and "where [...] at" are common, we can't say \*"to here" or \*"at there"; so I don't know if I agree that "there's no evident reason in grammar for prohibiting *where* as object of some prepositions and not others", if by that you mean that such a rule would make no sense if it existed.

Comment: @ruakh You make some good points; I will modify my Answer to address them.

Answer (score 2):

Of your first three examples, only the second is correct:

> Where did you go yesterday?

The preposition **to** is not omitted in this usage; rather, it is redundant and incorrect usage in the other two (although you will frequently hear "Where did you go to?" in colloquial American speech.) It is redundant because it is unnecessary: the meaning is clear without it.

In your other two examples, **to** is necessary because the meaning is *not* clear without it:

> Who(m) did you give the keys?

Comment: What makes the 'to' redundant? I can understand the sentence without it, maybe because I have heard enough of such sentences, but I can't understand the reason.

Comment: @Lemu17 It is redundant _because_ the sentence is clear without it. Similarly, "at" is redundant in "Where are you _at_?" See this [link](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/redundant?s=t).

Comment: Do certain verbs default to certain prepositions? Like as 'at' for 'be', because you would define the preposition in 'Where are you from?'

Comment: @Lemu17 If you are asking "Does _to go_ have to take _to_?" the answer is "No." _To go_ can be used without any preposition at all: _I go walking._ I don't understand "define the preposition."

Comment: There are many redundancies in English grammar which are not merely  permissible but obligatory--distinct 3psg endings, for instance, or most uses of the copula.

Comment: @StoneyB Don't see how this bears on the OP's question. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: It bears on your answer: specifically the implication that because *when ... to* is redundant it is incorrect.

Comment: @StoneyB I question whether it furthers a learner's purpose here to show him how _Where is he at?_ and _Where did you go to?_ are acceptable usages. If a friend asks me "Hey, where you stay at?" I do not excoriate him for his execrable redundancy. Here, though, I assume that our purpose is to show learners of English how to express themselves clearly in a way that will be useful to them in furthering their education or career.

Comment: This is a complicated place: some are learning English to pursue advanced studies, some want to learn the bizarre business dialect, some want to employ English socially--there are even a few who primarily want to read English literature. I think the only way we can address all these audiences is to discriminate as precisely as possible what uses are acceptable or preferred in what contexts, so they have a basis for choosing between them; and that appears to me to be exactly what OP asks for.